# Problem with configuring Netlify CMS with Git Gateway

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I am trying to use this Gatsby starter with Netlify CMS. https://github.com/stackrole-dev/gatsby-starter-foundation

I followed the instructions exactly but after enabling Git Gateway, when I try to login in as admin I encountered this error massage.

```
Your Git Gateway backend is not returning valid settings. Please make sure it is enabled.
```

I have no ideas why it is not working.

My `config.yml` is

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  commit_messages:
    create: 'Create {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    update: 'Update {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    delete: 'Delete {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    uploadMedia: '[skip ci] Upload “{{path}}”'
    deleteMedia: '[skip ci] Delete “{{path}}”'

local_backend: true # run npx netlify-cms-proxy-server for local testing

media_folder: "static/assets" 
public_folder: "/assets" 

collections:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable your settings for `git-gateway` and external providers in your Netlify as shown in [Netlify documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/visitor-access/git-gateway/#setup-and-settings):

[image: git-gateway]

This configuration can be found under https://app.netlify.com/sites/YOURNAME/settings/identity

In addition, your `config.yml` lacks:

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  repo: username/repository
  branch: master
```

Note: change `username` and `repository` for your names.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! I went back and set my external provider as Github but it still shows this error. I also enabled the git Gateway

Comment: Can you provide a piece of your `config.yml`?

Comment: Sure I edited my question to include the config file

Comment: Thanks @Joji! You didn't mention that it was a `local_backend`.  Did you try running `npx netlify-cms-proxy-server` and then try to login?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am pretty illiterate on these topics. The instructions on the git repo says after setting up the git gateway we can access the admin via site-name.netlify.app/admin/. So is this how I should access the CMS? i.e. using localhost/admiin and push to the git repo whenever I done editing?

Comment: Ideally, yes. You are missing some parameters in your `config.yml` that are updated in my answer. In addition, the way you described sets a local server when you run the command. If you are not using it, I would recommend to remove it since it's a beta feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What is the best practice here in your opinion? should I access CMS using the live site link like `site-name.netlify.app/admin/` or accessing it via local server?

Comment: Accessing locally removes the "issue" of pulling and rebasing all the time your local environment to fetch all the new data published in the site, however, in this case, being a beta (unstable) feature, I would remove it temporarily in order to solve your question issue. When your issue will be solved, you can try it locally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Last question: you mentioned that I should add `repo: username/repository` in `backend`. Is the `username` my github username and the `repository` the url to my git repo? For example, if the repo is, https://github.com/stackrole/gatsby-starter-foundation, the `repo: username/repository`  would be: `repo: stackrole/gatsby-starter-foundation`?

Comment: Yes, it's the slug of the repository. In your case would be: `repo: stackrole/gatsby-starter-foundation`

Answer (score 4):

You can enable `git-gateway`

Settings > Identity > Services

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue while configuring Netlify CMS. I faced this issue because I was passing master branch in Netlify CMS config but in GitHub repo my branch was main.My issue was resolved by changing branch `config.yaml`